# Structuring a program. Classes and functions in Python

Tags: python, parallel-python

I'm writing a program that uses genetic techniques to evolve equations.
I want to be able to submit the function 'mainfunc' to the Parallel Python 'submit' function.
The function 'mainfunc' calls two or three methods defined in the Utility class.
They instantiate other classes and call various methods.
I think what I want is all of it in one NAMESPACE.
So I've instantiated some (maybe it should be all) of the classes inside the function 'mainfunc'.
I call the Utility method 'generate()'. If we were to follow it's chain of execution
it would involve all of the classes and methods in the code.

Now, the equations are stored in a tree. Each time a tree is generated, mutated or cross
bred, the nodes need to be given a new key so they can be accessed from a dictionary attribute of the tree. The class 'KeySeq' generates these keys.

In Parallel Python, I'm going to send multiple instances of 'mainfunc' to the 'submit' function of PP. Each has to be able to access 'KeySeq'. It would be nice if they all accessed the same instance of KeySeq so that none of the nodes on the returned trees had the same key, but I could get around that if necessary.

So: my question is about stuffing EVERYTHING into mainfunc.
Thanks
(Edit) If I don't include everything in mainfunc, I have to try to tell PP about dependent functions, etc by passing various arguements in various places. I'm trying to avoid that.

(late Edit) if ks.next() is called inside the 'generate() function, it returns the error 'NameError: global name 'ks' is not defined'

```
class KeySeq:
    "Iterator to produce sequential \
    integers for keys in dict"
    def __init__(self, data = 0):
        self.data = data
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        self.data = self.data + 1
        return self.data
class One:
    'some code'
class Two:
    'some code'
class Three:
    'some code'
class Utilities:
    def generate(x):
        '___________'
    def obfiscate(y):
        '___________'
    def ruminate(z):
        '__________'


def mainfunc(z):
    ks = KeySeq()
    one = One()
    two = Two()
    three = Three()
    utilities = Utilities()
    list_of_interest = utilities.generate(5)
    return list_of_interest

result = mainfunc(params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all of the instances of `mainfunc` to use the same `KeySeq` object, you can use the default parameter value trick:

```
def mainfunc(ks=KeySeq()):
   key = ks.next()
```

As long as you don't actually pass in a value of `ks`, all calls to `mainfunc` will use the instance of `KeySeq` that was created when the function was defined.

Here's why, in case you don't know:  A function is an object.  It has attributes.  One of its attributes is named `func_defaults`; it's a tuple containing the default values of all of the arguments in its signature that have defaults.  When you call a function and don't provide a value for an argument that has a default, the function retrieves the value from `func_defaults`.  So when you call `mainfunc` without providing a value for `ks`, it gets the `KeySeq()` instance out of the `func_defaults` tuple.  Which, for that instance of `mainfunc`, is always the same `KeySeq` instance.

Now, you say that you're going to send "multiple instances of `mainfunc` to the `submit` function of PP."  Do you really mean multiple instances?  If so, the mechanism I'm describing won't work.

But it's tricky to create multiple instances of a function (and the code you've posted doesn't).  For example, this function does return a new instance of `g` every time it's called:

```
>>> def f():
        def g(x=[]):
            return x
        return g
>>> g1 = f()
>>> g2 = f()
>>> g1().append('a')
>>> g2().append('b')
>>> g1()
['a']
>>> g2()
['b']
```

If I call `g()` with no argument, it returns the default value (initially an empty list) from its `func_defaults` tuple.  Since `g1` and `g2` are different instances of the `g` function, their default value for the `x` argument is *also* a different instance, which the above demonstrates.

If you'd like to make this more explicit than using a tricky side-effect of default values, here's another way to do it:

def mainfunc():
      if not hasattr(mainfunc, "ks"):
          setattr(mainfunc, "ks", KeySeq())
      key = mainfunc.ks.next()

Finally, a super important point that the code you've posted overlooks:  If you're going to be doing parallel processing on shared data, the code that touches that data needs to implement locking.  Look at the `callback.py` example in the Parallel Python documentation and see how locking is used in the `Sum` class, and why.

Comment: I tried plugging in your 'default parameter trick'.
I got an error in the 'utilities.generate() method:
a = key
"NameError: global name 'key' is not defined"
I made sure 'mainfunc(ks = KeySeq())' was called without any parameters.
Right now I'm trying to get this to work with no reference to PP.
However, I'll study the second half of your message. And I'll refer to callback.py before bringing in PP.

Comment: I also tried the second method suggested, the 'more explicit' one.
It produced the same error in the same 'utilities.generate() method.

Comment: It sounds like you're under the misapprehension that `key` is visible outside of the `mainfunc` function.  It's not going to be available to `Utilities.generate()` unless you do something to make it so - make it an argument of the `generate` function, say, or pass it into the constructor, or set an attribute on the `Utilities` object after you instantiate it.  Or make it a module-level variable and reference it using `global`.  There are dozens of ways to do this, but you have to use one of them.

Comment: @Robert. I guess I'll just have to study up on scoping in Python. I learned from your answer and your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to structure your program that way. A lot of command line utilities follow the same pattern:

```
#imports, utilities, other functions

def main(arg):
    #...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

That way you can call the `main` function from another module by importing it, or you can run it from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Your concept of classes in Python is not sound I think.  Perhaps, it would be a good idea to review the basics.  This link will help.

[Python Basics - Classes](http://www.freenetpages.co.uk/hp/alan.gauld/tutclass.htm)